# How to insert rows in a table maintaining the style?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

The code works fine, but the new rows are different from the style of the table (the new rows are just blank). What should I do to add a row with the same style (color, border, width, height...) of the original table?

```
  var gtx = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var answer = gtx.alert('Do you want do add a row to the table?', gtx.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  while (answer == gtx.Button.YES) 
  {
     var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    var searchElement = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE);
    var element = searchElement.getElement();
    var tablecell = element.getParent();
    var tablerow = tablecell.getParent();
    var table = tablerow.getParent();
    var row = table.asTable().insertTableRow(table.getChildIndex(tablerow)+1);
        row.insertTableCell(0);
    var answer = gtx.alert('Do you want do add another row to the table?', gtx.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
     }
     }
```

The other code when I try to read and set the attributes.

```
function myFunction() {
 var gtx = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var answer = gtx.alert('Do you want do add a row to the table?', gtx.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  while (answer == gtx.Button.YES) 
  {
     var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
     var searchElement = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE);
      var element = searchElement.getElement();
      var table = element.asTable();
      var tablebc = table.getBorderColor();
      var tablebw = table.getBorderWidth();
      var tablecw = table.getColumnWidth(1)
      var style = {};
      style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] =
      DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
      style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_COLOR] = tablebc;
      style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH] = tablebw;
      style[DocumentApp.Attribute.WIDTH] = tablecw;
      var row = table.appendTableRow().appendTableCell();
        row.setAttributes(style);
    var answer = gtx.alert('Do you want do add another row to the table?', gtx.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
     }
     }
```

Comment: Use the associated, documented methods that *set* those *attributes* ?

Comment: @tehhowch I tried but couldn't make it work.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to read or set attributes in your code here

Comment: @tehhowch I tried with another code. I'll edit the post to include it.

Comment: And? Just writing code is not how you ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Share the errors, results, inputs, debugging logs - show the world you have tried to resolve this, and prevent others from needlessly repeating what you've already done.

Comment: I don't understand why you replied something like this...I don't know the errors, that's why I'm asking in the first place. I already said the results: blank rows. The only input is the button 'Yes' pressed by the user. And to be honest I don't know where to see my debugging logs. Anyway, thanks for your answers and suggestions!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#debugging

Answer (score 1):

Just played around with this issue too because I wanted to uniform all tables in a document.

It appears to me that 
setting the DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH does not have any effect neither on table or cell (using getCell).

Apparently its a bug.